# How do I populate a Data Access Layer Model Efficiently?

Tags: linq-to-sql, dependency-injection

I'm working on developing my first Data Driven Domain using Dependency Injection in ASP.net.

In my Data Access Layer if have created some domain data models, for example:

```
public class Company {
   public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee {
   public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have then developed an interface such as:

```
public interface ICompanyService {
   IEnumerable<Model.Company> GetCompanies();
   IEnumerable<Model.Employee> GetEmployees();
   IEnumerable<Model.Employee> GetEmployees(Guid companyId);
}
```

In a separate module I have implemented this interface using Linq to Sql:

```
public class CompanyService : ICompanyService {

    public IEnumerable<Model.Employee> GetEmployees();
    {
        return EmployeeDb
            .OrderBy(e => e.Name)
            .Select(e => e.ToDomainEntity())
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Where ToDomainEntity() is implemented in the employee repository class as an extension method to the base entity class:

```
public Model.EmployeeToDomainEntity()
{
     return new  Model.Employee {
         EmployeeId = this.EmployeeId,
         CompanyId = this.CompanyId,
         Name = this.Name
     };
}
```

To this point, I have more or less followed the patterns as described in Mark Seeman's excellent book 'Dependency Injection in .NET' - and all works nicely.

I would like however to extend my basic models to also include key reference models, so the domain Employee class would become:

```
public class Employee {
   public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
   public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
   public Company { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the ToDomainEntity() function would be extended to:

```
public Model.Employee ToDomainEntity()
{
     return new  Model.Employee {
         EmployeeId = this.EmployeeId,
         CompanyId = this.CompanyId,
         Company = (this.Company == null) ? null : this.Company.ToDomainEntity()
         Name = this.Name
     };
}
```

I suspect that this might be 'bad practice' from a domain modelling point of view, but the problem I have encountered would also, I think, hold true if I were to develop a specific View Model to achieve the same purpose.

In essence, the problem I have run into is the speed/efficiency of populating the data models. If I use the ToDomainEntity() approach described above, Linq to Sql creates a separate SQL call to retrieve the data for each Employee's Company record.  This, as you would expect, increases the time taken to evaluate the SQL expression quite considerably (from around 100ms to 7 seconds on our test database), particularly if the data tree is complex (as separate SQL calls are made to populate each node/sub-node of the tree).

If I create the data model 'inline...

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Employee> GetEmployees();
{
    return EmployeeDb
        .OrderBy(e => e.Name)
        .Select(e => new Model.Employee {
            EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
            /* Other field mappings */
            Company = new Model.Company {
               CompanyId = e.Company.CompanyId,
               /* Other field mappings */
            }
        }).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Linq to SQL produces a nice, tight SQL statement that natively uses the 'inner join' method to associate the Company with the Employee.

I have two questions:

1) Is it considered 'bad practice' to reference associated data classes from within a domain class object?

2) If this is the case, and a specific View Model is created for the purpose, what is the right way of populating the model using without having to resort to creating inline assignment blocks to build the expression tree?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you started developing, it would be better to pick Entity Framework (instead LINQ to SQL), since Microsoft will continue developing Entity Framework in the future.

Comment: Some additional research has suggested that the underlying problem here is the Linq (n+1) problem - which is well presented on StackOverflow.  As yet, I have not seen a good way of addressing this in the code - other than to create specific view models (which I was hoping to avoid).  I did find an article that suggested using an Expression<Func<a,b>> construct could be the answer, but I cannot find any examples of how this might be developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by having both data layer entities and domain layer entities and needing a mapping between the two. Although you can get this to work, this makes everything very complex, as you are already experiencing. You are making mappings between data and domain, and will soon add many more mappings for these same entities, because of performance reasons and because other business logic and presentation logic will need different data.

The only real solution is to ditch your data entities and create POCO model objects that can directly be serialized to your backend store (SQL server).

POCO entities is something that is supported in LINQ to SQL from day one, but I think it would be better to migrate to [Entity Framework Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).

When doing this, you can expose `IQueryable<T>` interfaces from your repositories (you currently called your repository `ICompanyService`, but a better name would be `ICompanyRepository`). This allows you to do efficient LINQ queries. When querying directly over a query provider you can prevent loading complete entities. For instance:

```
from employee in this.repository.GetEmployees()
where employee.Company.Name.StartWith(searchString)
select new 
{
    employee.Name, 
    employee.Company.Location 
};
```

When working with `IQueryable<T>`, LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework will translate this to a very efficient SQL query that only returns the employe name and company location from the database with filtering inside the database (compared to do filtering in your .NET application when `GetEmployees()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: Thanks Steven -  very useful.  I can see that this simplifies the model and it is pretty much what I did originally, but I was lead to believe that a 'better' approach was to use a Domain Driven Data model and Dependency Injection at the application level.  My current feeling is however that whilst I like the separation and modularity that it provides, it does seem like a lot more work and introduces some issues that were not there with a more direct coupling to the core SQL database.  I must confess, I am now having second thoughts on this route and am unsure as to the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Linq2Sql to preload certain entities (as opposed to lazy load them) using `DataLoadOptions.LoadWith` method see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx.
If you do this with the `Company` entity then I think Linq2Sql won't have to reach to the database to fetch it again.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I tried this but it didn't actually make any difference which I found surprising.  I think my only solid route forward is to remove the relationships from within the core data models and create specific view models where related data is required.  This seems to work well, though it does introduce some considerable overhead in creating the view models and providing mechanisms to populate them.

Comment: I was pretty sure that it does make a difference and checked a similar query in the AdventureWorks db. It works fine there.

Comment: First I ran this query:
`var dc = new UserQuery(this.Connection);
var query = dc.Products.Take(10);
query.Dump();`
and it produced a predictable SQL statement without any joins. But when I added the LoadOptions:
`var dc = new UserQuery(this.Connection);
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Product>(p => p.ProductSubcategory);
dc.LoadOptions = dlo;
var query = dc.Products.Take(10);
query.Dump();` it produced an SQL statement with a join to the Subcategory table.

Comment: Hi Pawel, this is strange as you are quite right, it does make a difference - but not always.  In my own code, presumably due to the structure, it does not work however, if I build the query with an Expression (rather than working with the IQueryable) then it works as expected.